# Adaptive Card appears as blank on MS Teams iOS app

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am trying to post Adaptive Card to MS Teams channel using python script. The message is rendered correctly on desktop app but nothing is displayed on iOS app.
iOS app build is 6.5.77.2024052102/0311 (general)/Release branch 2024Mar-T1.

[image: Desktop App Image]

[image: iOS App Image]

Here's my code snippet.

```py
import json
import requests

TEAMS_MESSAGE = {
   "type":"message",
   "attachments":[
        {
            "contentType":"application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
            "content":{
                "type":"AdaptiveCard",
                "body":[
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "text": "<at>John Doe</at>\n\nTest message.\n\n[Test hyperlink](https://www.example.com/)"
                    }
                ],
                "wrap": "true",
                "$schema":"http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
                "version":"1.5",
                "msteams": {
                    "entities": [
                        {
                            "type": "mention",
                            "text": "<at>John Doe</at>",
                            "mentioned": {
                                "id": "john_doe@contoso.com",
                                "name": "John Doe"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

WEBHOOK_URL = "https://contoso.webhook.office.com/webhookb2/xxxxx"
requests.post(WEBHOOK_URL, json.dumps(TEAMS_MESSAGE))
```

Any advice would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: We are able to repro this issue. We have raised a bug for the same. We will inform you once we get any further update from engineering team. Thanks!

Comment: Hello @Prasad-MSFT,
Thank you so much for your confirmation! If possible, please let me know once the bug is fixed.